# How do format 3 lines of information in the output together instead of them being separate?

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I'm trying to output two lines of code instead of two separate lines of code.

The output is twitter usernames and how many retweets they've made, using an excel sheet full of data with the module xlrl.

```py
for cell in sheet.col(23):
    print("username:",cell.value)

for cell in sheet.col(11):
    print("has:",cell.value, "retweets")

for cell in sheet.col(19):
    print("and mentioned:",cell.value)    

print(cell.value)
```

I expected an output of:

```
username: NicoletteColl20
has: 8.0 retweet
and mentioned: GhostKumi
```

However the output is:

```
-username: NicoletteColl20
-username: STEM_Portsmouth
-has: 8.0 retweets
-has: 188.0 retweets
-and mentioned: mentions
-and mentioned: GhostKumi
```

Comment: You need one loop that loops over rows of the sheet and prints the 3 cells from that row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your selected column has 2 rows, you need to iterate over the rows too.

One option is remove the rows that you don't want:

sheet: [A,B,Usernames,...,Retweets,..., Mentions,...,C,D]

mysheet:[Usernames,Retweets,Mentions]

And do something like this:

```
for r in mysheet.row:
    print("username:",r[0])
    print("has:",r[1], "retweets")
    print("and mentioned:",r[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip` to iterate through the columns at the same time, "side by side" (assuming the same number of elements in each column, otherwise some values in the longer columns won't be printed):

```
for c1, c2, c3 in zip(sheet.col(23), sheet.col(11), sheet.col(19)):
    print("username:",c1.value) 
    print("has:",c2.value, "retweets")
    print("and mentioned:",c3.value)
```